# Would not deleting the head in a linked list cause a memory leak?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm currently trying to make my own destructor for my Linked List class, and I know that I can't delete the head in the destructor because curr is using it in the code above, but would not deleting the head cause memory leaks in my code? Do I even need to set head equal to null?

```cpp
    ~LinkedList(){//Destructor
      Node*curr = head;
      Node* next = nullptr;

      while(curr->next != nullptr){
        next = curr->next;
        delete curr;
        curr = next;
      }
      head = nullptr;
      cout<<"Destructor called"<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you don't delete the pointers, you delete *the objects that the pointers point to*.  Given that, the posted code *does* delete the object that was pointed to by `head`, in its first iteration of the while-loop, because on the first iteration `curr` is set equal to `head` when you call `delete curr;`

Comment: Also, setting `head = nullptr;` isn't necessary in this case because you're at the end of the destructor, so nothing will ever look at the value of `head` again anyway.  Therefore it doesn't matter whether it's null or not.

Comment: And none of this complicated logic is necessary. It should take no more than four statements, including the while loop's condition, to safely delete the linked list. The shown algorithm leaks memory, in addition to being unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: In this case you can afford to do almost all of the work directly on `head` because `head`'s not going to be around much longer and doesn't need preservation. `while (head) { Node * temp = head; head = head->next; delete temp; }` That's pretty much it.

Comment: If you used smart pointers you could drastically simplify your code.

Comment: Yes, but you'll likely also limit the list size because destruction will become recursive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that I can't delete the head in the destructor because curr is using it in the code above

Then what you know is wrong, because you *can* and *must* free the `head` node, otherwise it will be leaked if the list is not empty.  Just because `curr` *points* to the `head` node does not mean you can't free that node.  Just don't use that pointer anymore until you reassign it to point at a different valid node.

> but would not deleting the head cause memory leaks in my code?

Yes.

> Do I even need to set head equal to null?

It is not strictly needed, no.  But it doesn't hurt anything, either.  Since the object being destructed is effectively dead to the outside world, any further access to it by outside code is *undefined behavior*, regardless of whether you set its `head` member to `nullptr` or not.

That said, the code you have shown is fine, except for 1 small mistake:

`while(curr->next != nullptr)`

needs to be changed to this instead:

`while(curr != nullptr)`

In your original code, if the list is empty, `curr` will be `nullptr` and so accessing `curr->next` will be *undefined behavior*. And if the list is not empty, the loop will skip freeing the *last* node in the list where `curr->next` will be `nullptr`.

The correct code should look like this:

```
~LinkedList(){//Destructor
  cout << "Destructor called" << endl;
  Node *curr = head, *next;
  while (curr != nullptr){
    next = curr->next;
    delete curr;
    curr = next;
  }
}
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
~LinkedList(){//Destructor
  cout << "Destructor called" << endl;
  while (head){
    Node *next = head->next;
    delete head;
    head = next;
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't think about that simplification, it makes complete sense to just increment the head since I'm not going to use it anymore lol

Answer (score 1):

```
while (head != nullptr) {
  Node* curr = head;
  head = head->next;
  delete curr;
}
```

The main thing making it "complicated" is the while condition: it should not be on a `next` field, the possible cause for a null pointer.

Then where you do your pointer juggling for *next* and *delete* there is some freedom of choice.

I find manipulating *head*  immediately makes the purpose quite clear.